# Transferring information between aws and wordpress/wix - iot - esp32

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, iot, esp32, velo

I'm building a small iot project, in this project I want to turn on/off a LED connected to ESP32 through a website (wix/wordpress) and aws in the middle.

I've managed to do that between the ESP32 and aws iot core service, but I'm not sure how can aws communicate with the website (it doesn't matter which platform, the easiest, and free).

I wish to make a button on the website, when it pressed it turns on/off the light, how can i transfer the relevant information from a button click to aws (and then to ESP32)?

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear from your question how AWS fits into your problem at all. Are you using the AWS IOT service?

Comment: Yes, I'm using AWS IOT core service, which communicates with the ESP32.
But I don't understand the other side communication between AWS and wordpress/wix.
ESP32 <-> AWS <-> wordpress/wix

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an AWS Lambda function that sends the on/off code to your IoT thing. You would expose that Lambda function via an HTTP or REST (AWS API Gateway) endpoint.

Then in your website, you would call that endpoint when the button is clicked. Wordpress and Wix are two totally different website platforms, so the fact that you are asking about both makes the question unclear. In general you would lookup the method of communicating with an HTTP endpoint, REST endpoint, or "webhook" in the web platform you are using.